# Infragistics ultragrid cells not being selected

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, infragistics, ultrawingrid

When i press `ctrl` and hold `left button` on mouse and drag it across the grid.

Cells are not being selected. What am i lagging? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you set somewhere in your application [SelectTypeCell](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2015.2/CLR4.0/html/Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v15.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.SelectType.html) to None, Single or SingleAutoDrag. If so, change it to Extended or ExtendedAutoDrag.